# How To Figure Out Cassandra Extra Off-Heap Memory Usage

Tags: cassandra

I have nodes which have 32GB Ram. I set 20 GB heap size. I am aware of cassandra uses off-heap for memtable, cache etc. Even though usage of memory is very low by memtable, cache etc, somehow cassandra uses 27GB memory. How can I figure out, how cassandra uses that extra 7GB memory?

Answer (score 2):

You can get metrics with [JConsole](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsMonitoring.html)

Or you can use Jolokia agent. For that download and set up jolokia agent to your Cassandra node. E.g.on Linux

```
mkdir /opt/jolokia
cd /opt/jolokia
wget https://github.com/rhuss/jolokia/releases/download/v1.4.0/jolokia-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz
tar -xf jolokia-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz
```

Add the agent path as a JVM option to the end of your cassandra-env.sh file and restart cassandra

```
echo 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia-1.4.0/agents/jolokia-jvm.jar"' >> /etc/conf/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
```

Restart Cassandra.

Then you can query metrics like:

*Total on heap memory:*

```
wget http://localhost:8778/jolokia/read/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage
```

*Total off heap memory:*

```
wget http://localhost:8778/jolokia/read/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Memory/NonHeapMemoryUsage
```

*Off heap memory used by memtables:*

```
wget http://localhost:8778/jolokia/read/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=*,scope=*,name=MemtableOffHeapSize
```

*And also for Bloomfilter, IndexSummary and Compression metadata:*

```
wget http://localhost:8778/jolokia/read/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=*,scope=*,name=BloomFilterOffHeapMemoryUsed
wget http://localhost:8778/jolokia/read/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=*,scope=*,name=IndexSummaryOffHeapMemoryUsed
wget http://localhost:8778/jolokia/read/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=*,scope=*,name=CompressionMetadataOffHeapMemoryUsed
```

---

UPDATE:
Example response from Jolokia endpoint:

```
{
   "request":{
      "mbean":"org.apache.cassandra.metrics:keyspace=*,name=CompressionMetadataOffHeapMemoryUsed,scope=*,type=Table",
      "type":"read"
   },
   "value":{
      "org.apache.cassandra.metrics:keyspace=my_keyspace,name=CompressionMetadataOffHeapMemoryUsed,scope=my_table_name,type=Table":{
         "Value":832
      },
      "org.apache.cassandra.metrics:keyspace=system,name=CompressionMetadataOffHeapMemoryUsed,scope=compaction_history,type=Table":{
         "Value":64
      },
      "org.apache.cassandra.metrics:keyspace=my_keyspace,name=CompressionMetadataOffHeapMemoryUsed,scope=my_table_name2,type=Table":{
         "Value":8184
      },
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: direct byte buffers are also used by netty and messaging which wouldnt necessarily be covered by the C* metrics. Sending large mutations or large select queries especially concurrently can increase the usage considerably.

Comment: other options if dont want to enable jolokia is to use [sjk](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools) or [jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/)

Comment: Thank you for response @Andrea  but I cannot see "Memory" section on Mbean. I used JConsole to checked out mbean. This is the link What I saw. The "Memory section" is special for jolokia?

Comment: I updated my response with an example jolokia response. It is a simple json with the size of the off heap memory per keyspace per table for the specific metric (e.g. CompressionMetadataOffHeapMemoryUsed in my example).You should be able to see the exact same value with JConsole.

Comment: @AndreaNagy using this link, https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSjk.html I dumped all metrics, My cassandra uses 27GB memory, When I sum the all memory values, It equals to 8GB memory. Is there any field that uses memory?